# Unbuffered communication between C++ and Python

Tags: c++, python, pipe, popen, unbuffered

I want to pass data from C++ to Python in Linux and I do this through a pipe.
My C++ program looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sstream>
#include<math.h>

int main() {
    FILE *cmd;

    std::ostringstream ss;
    double val;

    cmd = popen("python plot.py","w");
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        val = cos(3.14159*i/40);
        ss.str("");
        ss << val << std::endl;
        fputs(ss.str().c_str(),cmd);
        fflush(cmd);
    }
    fputs("\n",cmd);
    fflush(cmd);
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;     
}
```

The corresponding python function plot.py looks like:

```
fig, = plt.plot([],[])
index = 0
plt.ion()
while True:
    data = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    if not data:
        plt.ioff()
        break
    index = index + 1
    val = [float(n) for n in self.data.split()]

    fig.set_xdata(numpy.append(fig.get_xdata(),index))
    fig.set_ydata(numpy.append(fig.get_ydata(),val))
    axis = list(plt.axis())
    min_x = 0      
    max_x = max(self.fig.get_xdata())
    min_y = min(self.fig.get_ydata())
    max_y = max(self.fig.get_ydata())
    axis[0] = min_x
    axis[1] = max_x
    axis[2] = min_y
    axis[3] = max_y
    plt.axis(axis)
    plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Now my problem is that there seems to be a buffering of data from my c++ function before data is being passed to the python function, which I am not able to get rid of. I have searched for a solution but have not been able to find any. The best suggestion I could find was to use setvbuf in the c++ function, so I also tried to include the following line to the c++ function

```
setvbuf(cmd,NULL,_IONBUF,0)
```

But that did not have any effects.

Does anyone know how I can pass data from my c++ function to python in an unbuffered manner?

Comment: You really don't describe the problem. You say there *seems* to be buffering, but give no indication *why* you think that. What is the actual problem you are having? What makes you think there's buffering and what do you hope to gain by getting rid of it?

Comment: Try adding a new-line at the end of each `fputs` stream.

Comment: Not only is your explanation of the actual problem is unclear, but your Python code is incomplete.  As David pointed out, it's hard to answer your question without more information.

Comment: You are outputting a single line from your C++ program, so the `sys.stdin.readline()` *must* buffer the input until it receives a `\n`, at least this is the semantics of `readline()`. There are some tricks to set python's `stdin` into unbuffered mode, but then you must use plain `read`s if I'm not mistaken.